# Kubernetes on Windows Persistent Volume

Tags: windows-10, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Does windows minikube support a persistent volume with a hostpath? If so what is the syntax?

I tried:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: kbmongo002
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: mongostorageclass
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/temp/mongo"
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
---
```

This passed validation and created the PV and a PVC claimed it, but nothing was written to my expected location of C:\temp\mongo

I also tried:

```
  hostPath:
    path: "c:/temp/mongo"
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
---
```

That resulted in:

```
Error: Error response from daemon: Invalid bind mount spec 
"c:/temp/mongo:/data/db": invalid mode: /data/db 
Error syncing pod
```

Comment: how are you mounting your host folder into the VM?

Answer (score 2):

If you use virtualbox in windows, only the `c:/Users` is mapped into vm as `/c/Users` which is kubernetes system can access. It is the feature in Virtualbox.

[image: snapshot]

Minikube use VM to simulate the kubernetes VM.

Minikube provides mount feature as well, not so user-friendly for persitency.

You can try choose one of the solutions below

- use folders under `/c/Users` for your yaml file
- map extra folders into virtualbox VM like `C:\Users`
- use `minikube mount`, see [host folder mount](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/host_folder_mount.md)

Comment: can you please tell me if this issue is related to my issue? for Linux mounting works OK but I have issues with windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709259/kubernetes-cannot-have-windows-path-mounted-on-azure-file-share-linux-mountin

Answer (score 1):

I have tried k8s hostpath on windows, it works well. 
You should use drive letter in pod mount path, see example: https://github.com/andyzhangx/Demo/blob/master/windows/azuredisk/aspnet-pod-azuredisk.yaml#L14

As there is a docker mount path related bug on windows, you need to use drive letter as mount path in pod, see issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34729

Comment: can you please tell me if this issue is related to my issue? for Linux mounting works OK but I have issues with windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709259/kubernetes-cannot-have-windows-path-mounted-on-azure-file-share-linux-mountin